# Where I've participated on the page?

Tags: feature-request, search, keyboard-shortcuts

Sometimes when I revisit an old page, and I remember having left comments, I'd like to quickly jump to them.

So the first thing I do is CTRL+F my name,

```
bobobobo
```

Actually what happens is my name at the top of the page is highlighted.  I press enter and it jumps down to the next comment/answer I've made.. ***unless the comment is folded away***!   Then all hell breaks loose.  I run to the fridge, get some soda water to cool me down.  I sit down at the desk again, and it look that all hope is lost.  I frantically click *show x more comments*, and finally find my own comment.

At peace, I close the browser window and get back to what I was doing.

Wouldn't it be nice to have a shortcut key to jump to "**See my next contribution**" in the page?  Something like `CTRL`+`ALT`+`C`.  Folded away contributions would be automatically expanded.  Also, this way, the first result wouldn't go to the top of the page (username).

Comment: Better yet, a "show all" view that expands all comments, and removes pagination (showing all answers on the same page).  I don't know how expensive that would be, though.

Comment: Nice idea! @RobertHarvey: That would be great on *most* pages. The [Formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122) probably belongs to the other category...

Comment: @robert that's scriptable :) I'll add that to my userscript to-do list. Pretty simple--fetch pages via ajax, feed to jQuery, append, click all comment expanders. Easy-peasy :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey probably not significantly expensive considering it'd be rarely used. Cheapest AJAX call is one you don't make